# uDeploy process executes in isolation but not when grouped with other processes...

Tags: windows-installer, udeploy

I'm currently working on the setup of uDeploy for one of our web applications.

For our Development environment, I have established an Install component with associated Deploy process. 
The Deploy process in turn consists of three processes: Uninstall, Install & Copy web.config as shown below:

[image]

I am experiencing some unexpected issues when attempting to execute the Deploy process...

If the application MSI is already installed on the target server, the Uninstall process executes successfully as expected; the uDeploy process log screen shows the successful execution, as does a visit to the now empty application folder on the target server.

However, when the Deploy process progresses to the Install stage, nothing happens - the Install process does not execute, showing "Already Installed" status, despite the successful Uninstall process completed previously (see below), before progressing onto and successfully executing the web.config copy process.

The end result is an application folder on the server containing nothing but the web.config.

[image]

To recap: each of the three (sub)processes in the Deploy process function correctly and as expected when executed in isolation; when these processes are chained together, the Install process will not execute, indication a status of "Already Installed" despite recently completed Uninstall process execution.

Has anyone else who's worked with uDeploy experienced similar issues?

What was the cause of the problem?

How was it resolved?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated; thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue turned out to be quite simple, once I'd identified it. The 'Only Changed Versions' checkbox was ticked by default:

[image]

Once this was unchecked and the process restarted, all process steps executed successfully.

When running the process in isolation as a component process, this option is not available, hence the process originally ran successfully in isolation as a component process but would not execute as part of an application process.

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4GSP_6.0.1/com.ibm.udeploy.doc/topics/deployment_ch.html